# How to be certain of running linux command in English?

Tags: linux, command, locale

I'm writing some software that uses the output of some system (linux) commands.

Problem is, it fails with languages other than english.

Is there a way to run linux commands **and be sure** that they'll run in English?

There's a 90% solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/142814/906745), with an exception handled [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/311796/906745)

But neither shows a fail-safe way of ensuring a command is executed in English

For convenience, the 90% solution was to prepend commands with `LANG=C`

The exception handles for when `LANGUAGE` environment is aleady defined (then it will take priority over `LANG`, in which case prepending commands with `LANGUAGE=C` will solve.

Not sure how to solve for both cases? (I guess prepending `LANG=C LANGUAGE=C`)

Comment: It looks like you already have a solution.

Comment: @larsks i am not so sure. There could be other conditions that override the above two, things I am not aware of

Comment: Doesn't `LC_ALL=C cmd` solve your problem?

Comment: @Isaac according to [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale) it won't if `LANGUAGE` is set

Comment: Then use `LANGUAGE=C LC_ALL=C cmd` or, maybe: `unset LANGUAGE; LC_ALL=C cmd`